# How to submit an Angular Project

Tags: angular, project

I created an Angular project in my PC for a academic project. It has Angular material, SweetAlert2 etc. If I submit this project, Can the evaluator run my project on his PC without installing Node, Angular CLI, Angular materials and other packages which I used. What are the installations he should have done before running my project in Localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular project can not be run without NodeJS on the target system, but in your case, the solution is to create a production build using the Angular CLI and then deploy it on a simple web server.

I'm assuming your project doesn't depend on any other service (such as a database), in which case, you can follow [this deployment guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simple-deployment-options) on the Angular website.

Comment: Should the Evaluator install any additional packages like Angular material, sweetAlert2?

Comment: If he install only NodeJs , will it run?

Comment: The evaluator would only need to setup the web server and nothing else.